# "The plus symbol indicates that this should be created as a new ID" - as opposed to what?

Tags: android, xml

When Android describes `android:id` as:

> Resource ID. A unique resource ID for this drawable. To create a new resource ID for this item, use the form: "@+id/name". The plus symbol indicates that this should be created as a new ID.

When would `id` not be created as a *new* `id`? Shouldn't that be implied?

Answer (score 1):

Views in a layout file can reference other views. This happens frequently when using RelativeLayout or ConstraintLayout which needs explicit relationships to be formed between its children.

e.g.

```
    <Button android:id="@+id/progress" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/progress" />
```

When you specify a reference to another view, you omit the `+` because we're not creating the ID, but referencing an existing one.

Comment: But the reference is implied because it's not in the `id` attribute. If it is in the id attribute creating a new id should be implied?

Comment: Ah, that's a good point. Technically you _can_ use the `+` syntax to create IDs outside of the ID field, so maybe the SDK authors felt it was good for flexibility and consistency. Though I can't think of any time you would need to create an ID but couldn't use the `id` property itself ‍♂️